# assert 0, 'error' vs raise AssertionError('error')

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why would one use `assert False, 'error'` vs `raise AssertionError('error')`?

Comment: In this specific case, it should instead raise a `NotImplementedError`

Comment: Note that neither of these are adequate uses. ``NotImplementedError`` should be raised instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this:

1. You can then disable the assertion, by running your Python scripts with the `-O` switch.
2. Using `assert` gives consistency with other uses of `assert`, in the more common cases where the assertion is non-constant rather than just  `0`. (But `False` should really be used instead.)